# physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart() creating phantom println (reads 'Chance') - override println function?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, println, skphysicsworld

I'm using Sprite Kit's built-in physics engine in a game I'm writing. In order to check whether or not a character is on the ground, I'm using the `bodyAlongRayStart()` function of the `SKScene`'s `physicsWorld` to check for bodies underneath the bottom-left and bottom-right corners of the character (this function belong's to the character's class):

```
func isInAir(sceneRef:GameScene) -> Bool {
    var isInAir:Bool = false

    let distance:CGFloat = 32 // how far from the origin we should check

    // define where the rays start and end
    let bottomLeftRayStart:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.position.x - (self.hitbox.size.width/2), y: self.position.y - (self.hitbox.size.height/2))
    let bottomLeftRayEnd:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.position.x - (self.hitbox.size.width/2), y: (self.position.y - (self.hitbox.size.height/2) - distance))
    let bottomRightRayStart:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.position.x + (self.hitbox.size.width/2), y: self.position.y - (self.hitbox.size.height/2))
    let bottomRightRayEnd:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.position.x + (self.hitbox.size.width/2), y: (self.position.y - (self.hitbox.size.height/2) - distance))

    // Are there any bodies along the lines?
    var bottomLeftBody:SKPhysicsBody! = sceneRef.physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart(bottomLeftRayStart, end:bottomLeftRayEnd)
    var bottomRightBody:SKPhysicsBody! = sceneRef.physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart(bottomRightRayStart, end:bottomRightRayEnd)

    // no bodies found
    if bottomLeftBody == nil && bottomRightBody == nil {
        isInAir = true
    } else {
        // if one of the rays finds a wall (floor) or slope, we're not in the air
        if (bottomLeftBody != nil && (bottomLeftBody!.categoryBitMask == _entityType.wall.rawValue || bottomLeftBody!.categoryBitMask == _entityType.slope.rawValue)) || (bottomRightBody != nil && (bottomRightBody.categoryBitMask == _entityType.wall.rawValue || bottomRightBody!.categoryBitMask == _entityType.slope.rawValue)) {
            isInAir = false
        }
    }
    return isInAir
}
```

This code is called in the scene's `update()` function (though I should probably move it to `didSimulatePhysics()`...) and it works fine! What's annoying, however, is that Swift in its infinite wisdom decides to print `Chance` to the console every time it detects a body along the ray.

With only one character in the scene it's not too much of a bother, but I'll be adding enemies soon (who work in much the same way, but will have different functions for handling their movement) and all those `println()` calls will slow the simulator right down. I can't see a way to suppress this; the call is coming from the class library which I can't alter.

Is there a reliable way to override the standard `println()` function, gloabally? Something like this:

```
func println(object: Any) {
    #if DEBUG
        Swift.println(object)
    #endif
}
```

And if so, where in my project should I put it? It's currently in `AppDelegate.swift` but other libraries (and the `bodyAlongRayStart()` function) are still printing to the console even when I change the flag...

Answer (score 3):

I submitted this bug to Apple. They told me it's fixed in the next version of Xcode. If it's really bugging you, you can download Xcode 6.3 beta.

Comment: Not fixed in 6.2 (latest release) >:(

Comment: Really that sucks.. Apple recommended I get 6.2 beta. Said it was fixed there. It's really annoying since it spams the console =\